# TX and RX on single wire

Tags: voltage

Here I am not using any RS232 or RS485 protocols. I will transmit analog square signal of -12 to +12V and also receive the -12V to +12V signal. So I have a circuit which can transmit and receive the signal individually.
2 circuits are constructed the schematic is attached below.

The process is
First setup-1 will transmit the signal for T1 time period then after T1 period it will not transmit it will be in idle state i.e. 0V for T2 time period, in this T2 time period, the setup receive the signal and transmit the signal to setup-1 for T1 period in T2 period only. After that the setup again transmit the signal for T1 period and Setup transmit the signal for T3 period .. so on it will continue.

In this testing i have  faced a problem that when both setups are connected each other and while doing the above testing process , the oscilloscope was connected between 2 setups for observing the voltage.. here the voltage which should be -12V to +12V it was dropped to -6 to +6V ..

can anyone please suggest any solution to this issue i.e, voltage dropping issue

[image]
[image]

Comment: "*can anyone please suggest any solution to this issue?*" Without a schematic? Probably not.

Comment: What chips or devices those are driving the common data wire? How are they connected? We can't guess what are you doing, you should give much more detailed info.

Answer (score 2):

`it will be in idle state i.e. 0V`
So your receiving device is still driving the output with low impedance to 0V? You will have to switch the pin to a high impedance state in the receiving phase, otherwise the two drivers override each other. This explains why your signal amplitude is reduced to half of the expected amplitude (because you have a voltage divider of the two driver impedances: +12V -> R -> 6V -> R -> 0V).

Be careful with this setup, these settings will result in a high current from these pins. The TX driver might not be designed to withstand these currents for long. But we have no way of knowing this, since you did not tell us what hardware you use...

Comment: It's quite difficult to keep them synchronized, unless your timings are very slow (+12/-12 is also quite a slew to do… are you doing AMI modulation?)

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Was this comment aimed at me or the original post? ;)

Comment: Why is idle 0V when your voltage swing is -12V to +12V? At the uart level, idle is a logic high. RS232 inverts this.